# How to find out about what N the resample function in pandas did its job?

Tags: python, pandas

I use the python module `pandas` and its function `resample` to calculate means of a dataset. I wonder how I can get to know about what N the resampling for each day/each month takes places.
In the below given example I calculate means for the three month January, Feb. and March.
The answer to my question in that case is: N for January = 31, N for February = 29, N for March = 31. Is there a way to get that information about N for more complex data?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#create dates as index
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=91)
index = pd.Index(dates, name = 'dates')

#create DataFrame df
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(91, 1), index, columns=['A'])

print df['A']
#calculate monthly_mean
monthly_mean = df.resample('M', how='mean')
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `how='count'`, IIUC:

```
>>> df.resample('M', how='count')
2000-01-31  A    31
2000-02-29  A    29
2000-03-31  A    31
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks. That answers my specific question but new problems occur. I also need the mean values. Now I have just 'A' in that column. I also need to turn the date into a data column which I did using `monthly_mean.reset_index(inplace=True)`. This doesn't work anymore.